# regular expression for square brackets with dot

Tags: c#, jquery

I am using a regular expression:

^[0-9a-zA-Z/[] ._',()\n-"]+$

Its working fine in all the scenario, but I am stuck at a point, when I am trying to enter a square bracket after dot its not working for me.

```
its working for me when i am trying for

.[

or

.]

expression shows
```

a. dot+square start+space

b. dot+square end+space

```
combination when i am trying its not working for me

.[

or

.]

expression shows
```

a. dot+square start

b. dot+square end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to escape the special chars.  You probably need something like:

```
^[0-9a-zA-Z/\[\] \._',\(\)\n\-"]+$
```

**EDIT**

Because you've not escaped your special chars, the regular expression is broken, it's matching some things in the first group, followed by a space, followed by any char (represented by the dot/period), etc.

Have you tried the above?  If you want to comment, it's best to comment in the comments section below my answer (I noticed that you'd tried to edit my answer).

**EDIT 2**

If you're trying to match a dot followed by a square bracket, then you want:

```
^\.[\[\]]$
```

Comment: when i am trying the expression 
^[0-9a-zA-Z/\[\] \._',\(\)\n\-"]+$
its working for me in 1st scenario, but when i am removing the space from expression its not working for both the scenario.

Comment: Have you tried the regex I've provided with the escaped characters?

Comment: yes i have tried the same regex that you provided me.
but i am facing issue in 2nd scenario.

Comment: Can you post more detail about what you're trying to do/match and some code examples?